# JavaFX: No window is showing after using javapackager

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx

So I have created a `JavaFX8` project in `IntelliJ` and everything worked fine in there. I ran it with the same arguments outside `IntelliJ`, everything worked too. However, when I use `javapackager` to create an executable with the same arguments and run the created executable, no window is showing. Does anyone know why it is? Thanks a lot!

The following are the commands I used ([very-long-list-of-class-paths] are the same in all three commands):

Running in `IntelliJ`:

> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7540
>   "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=F:\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1\bin"
>   -Dfile.encoding=GBK -classpath [very-long-list-of-class-paths] com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain danIDE.Main

Running in `cmd`:

> java -classpath [very-long-list-of-class-paths] danIDE.Main

Using `javapackager`:

> javapackager -makeall -v -classpath [very-long-list-of-class-paths]  -appclass danIDE.Main -name DanIDE

Comment: Are you trying to say that the package created by the `javapackager` doesn't show anything?

Comment: Does the `jar` created before creating the package works as expected?

Comment: hmm... it doesn't work and says `could not find or load main class dist.jar`. @ItachiUchiha

Comment: So the problem is with the jar. You can try creating an artifact using InteliiJ built in JavaFX packager or you can use the `javapackager -createjar` for creating one. First, make sure the jar works, then you may proceed to make a distribution.